# SKPSMTPMessage library

Tags: ios, xcode, skpsmtpmessage

I am getting the error you see in the photo when I import the SKPSMTPMessage library:

[image]

The point is that I have no idea what it means. I have done a clean, I have added the files under the Compile Sources, and I have added the CFNetwork framework. Any idea what it means??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting all sorts of "duplicate symbol errors" getting spewed because the same symbols are defined in both a file you're including ("`Base64Transcoder.m`") and a SDK you are including (the DropBox SDK).  So the compiler doesn't know which symbol you really want to use at run time.

I recommend *removing* "`Base64Transcoder.m`" from your project, at least temporarily, to see if all those duplicate symbol errors go away.

Comment: Yes but one of the other files requires it (#import "Base64Transcoder.h").

Comment: All you need is the "`.h`" file, you don't need the "`.m`" file (since the symbols it defines are already delivered and exposed in the DropBox SDK).